# html URL pattern for the url can be start with www. also

Tags: html

I need to find a regex pattern for URLs that can start with `http://` or `https://` or `www.`, eg: `www.stackoverflow.com`.

I found this:

```
<input type="url" id="myURL" name="website" pattern="https?://.+" title="Include http://">
```

It works for `http://` and `https://`, but I need pattern  validation for `www.` also.

Comment: Need more info. Can you show some code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

for using your own pattern please change input type as text instead of url.